# Style specific rows in multiindex dataframe

Tags: pandas, multi-index, styling

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like:

```
Year                          2019                   2020               
Decision                   Applied Admitted     % Applied Admitted     %
Class         Residency                                                 
Freshmen      Resident      1143.0    918.0  80.3  1094.0   1003.0  91.7
              Non-Resident  1371.0   1048.0  76.4  1223.0   1090.0  89.1
              Total         2514.0   1966.0  78.2  2317.0   2093.0  90.3
Transfer      Resident       404.0    358.0  88.6   406.0    354.0  87.2
              Non-Resident   371.0    313.0  84.4   356.0    288.0  80.9
              Total          775.0    671.0  86.6   762.0    642.0  84.3
Grad/Postbacc Total          418.0    311.0  74.4   374.0    282.0  75.4
Grand         Total         3707.0   2948.0  79.5  3453.0   3017.0  87.4
```

*note: Full MWE is in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75479701/8954291) question.*

I'm trying to italicize the total rows (here that's rows 3,6,7,8) and bold the grand total row (row 8) in a way that doesn't rely on actual row numbers.

I can do that with:

```py
df_totals.style.apply(lambda x:["font-style: italic;"]*len(x),subset=((slice(None),"Total"),))\
               .applymap_index(lambda x:"font-style: italic;" if x in ("Grand","Total") else "")
```

[image]

That just seems super unpythonic, ugly, and unmaintainable to me, especially the call to `applymap_index`. Is there a more fluent way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

First part should be simplify by [`Styler.set_properties`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.set_properties.html), second part is good in my opinion, there is only small change by example in [`Styler.applymap_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.applymap_index.html):

```
df_totals.style.set_properties(**{'font-style': 'italic'}, subset=((slice(None),"Total"),))
         .applymap_index(lambda x:"font-style: italic;" if x in ("Grand","Total") else None)
```

Comment: I think it might be `subset=((slice(None),"Total"),)`, actually. Tuple vs parens issue strikes again